# How to disable / stub out any Rails ActiveRecord call for one test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, rspec-rails

Let say I'm replacing functionality in Ruby on Rails of particular piece of code  from `ActiveRecord::Base` functionality to `ElasticSearch` object model (So that no PostgeSQL / MySQL / SQL is called when hitting that object is called. E.G. serializer for search endpoint `/works/search`

So how to ensure in RSpec that no SQL call is made  when retrieving data (e.g. test will raise exception if SQL call was made via ActiveRecord)

Answer (score 0):

Stubbing out `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` should do the trick.

One thing to watch out for is  to stub out after all preparations (`Arrange` part of test) are done. For example `before(:each)` could be cleaning database before the tests are run => ActiveRecord.connection is triggered, you may be creating some record that will be indexed by ElasticSearch => ActiveRecord.connection is called.

so something like this:

```
class WorksSearchSerializer
  attr_reader :collection

  def initialize(collection)
    @collection
  end

  def as_json
    [
      {
        id: work.id
        comment_ids: work.comments.map(&:id)
        # ... other stuff that may trigger ActiveRecord call
      }
    ]
  end
end

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe WorksSearchSerializer do
  ShouldNotDoAnyDBConnection = Class.new(StandardError)

  subject { described_class.new(es_works)  }
  let!(:work) { Work.create!  } #this triggers ActiveRecord::Base.connection call
  let(:es_works) { Work.__elasticsearch__.search({query: { match_all: {} }}.to_json) }
  let(:result) { subject.as_json }

  before do
    sleep 0.2 # wait for ES reindex
  end

  it 'should not pull any relational DB records' do  
    allow(ActiveRecord::Base)
      .to receive(:connection)
      .and_raise(ShouldNotDoAnyDBConnection)

    expect(result).to be_kind_of Array

    allow(ActiveRecord::Base)
      .to receive(:connection)
      .and_call_original
  end

end
```